# android SELECT MAX not work

Tags: java, sqlite

I have tested this select in SQLite and it works but, when I use this in Android, it returns 0.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!!

```
final String idauto = bundle.getString("idtabella");

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

final SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
final Cursor cursordati = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX('in_auto') AS in_auto "
    + "FROM inout WHERE id_auto ='" + idauto + "'", null);

final int  Ingressi = cursordati.getColumnIndex("in_auto");  
if(cursordati.moveToFirst()){  
    TextV.append("iprova: "+ Ingressi); 
    do {
        TextV.append("dprova: "+ Ingressi); 
    } while (cursordati.moveToNext());
    TextV.append("wprova: "+ Ingressi); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just put

```
cursordati.moveToFirst();
```

before

```
final int  Ingressi = cursordati.getInt(0);
```

It works :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you thing you have a problem. You're asking for the column *index* for a query with exactly one column. Since the index is zero-based, you *will* get zero.

If you want to get the actual *value* of `max(in_auto)` instead of its index, you should probably try:

```
final int  Ingressi = cursordati.getInt(cursordati.getColumnIndex("in_auto"));
```

or probably just:

```
final int  Ingressi = cursordati.getInt(0);
```

would be fine, as long as you remember to check and possibly change it if you ever modify the query.

Comment: Not work give error!
06-02 11:45:16.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6111): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: Then you're getting -1 for the column index, not zero as you seem to have stated. You need to figure that out first. Can I ask why you have `max('in_auto')` instead of just `max(in_auto)`?

Comment: tested al MAX(x),MAX('x') and "'" + idauto + "'"  " + idauto + "" same error... 

Index -1 requested, with a size of 1